# Why is my Magento2 di.xml not having any effect?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

I've overridden `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer` and when I add this to the end of config in `/app/etc/di.xml` the override works.

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="Tls\Module\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" />
```

However, when I try to use `/app/code/Tls/Module/etc/di.xml` there is no effect. This is the contents of my `di.xml` (though I've tried many things)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="Tls\Module\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" />
</config>
```

Magento 2.2.4

Comment: Is the module enabled?

Comment: Yes. It has a registered route that is working appropriately.

Comment: Also, I'm in development mode and I've tried clearing the cache.

Comment: OK so if you have a route working in that module namespace I assume you have a proper working composer.json/registration.php?

Comment: registration.php: yes. composer.json: no. Is it required?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue? I am having the same issue...no generated/code/{namespace}/{module} files after compiling the DI.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29436 isnt working on 2.4.2 too